# libgdx texture's alpha value changed

Tags: opengl, libgdx

so I have a problem with the alpha value in my texture. Basically the pixmap is set all black then  I drew a filled circle with the alpha value set to 0 in order for the area of the circle  it to be transparent (yes I set blending to none), then I created the texture out of the pixmap like this:

```
Texture myTexture = new Pixmap(TransparentCirclePixmap); // this constructor takes a pixmap
```

if I draw this texture the circle is not transparent it has a color that is not the background in my game.

so basically what i want is to draw a transparent circle in my pixmap and create a texture from that pixmap and when I draw the texture to the screen the interior of the circle displays whatever was in the background of my game.

Comment: You could create a .png Image using gimp or photoshop, where you simply cut out a circle in the middle. Then in libgdx you have to enable blending (ist actually enabled by default)